# How to display a table followed by a figure in succession in IPython notebook without repeated figures at the end?

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, jupyter-notebook

For example, I want to print 10 random numbers, then plot and display a figure underneath the printed random numbers, and I want to do this 3 times:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from IPython import display

for _ in range(3):
    x = np.random.randn(10)
    print(x)
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.plot(x, x + 5, 'x')
    display.display(plt.gcf())
```

At the end of the output, the 3 figures are displayed again, one after another.  Is there a way not to have these repeated at the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution should work.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from IPython import display
%matplotlib inline

for _ in range(3):
    x = np.random.randn(10)
    print(x)
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.plot(x, x + 5, 'x')
    display.display(plt.gcf())
    plt.close()
```

Since there are no open figures at the end of the execution of this cell, no additional plots are generated.

Comment: Even if this code solves your problem, I would suggest not accepting it right away. Maybe the ipython folks have a nicer solution :)

Comment: You could even call the `plt.close()` right after the `display.display..` call. This way you don't need the additional loop and the _pylabtools_ import